# How to make a link bold and underlined on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

For my menu, I want to make the link bold and underlined when moving over it.

I just found out how to change the color and how to make it bigger.

What is the syntax for making it bold and underlined?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `:hover` selector

```
a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Answered my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

target the `hover` state on the `a` or add a `class` if you want to target a specific link

```
a:hover{
   font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code appear for all the links

```
a:hover {
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

If u want only for the menu just go with this

```
#menu li a:hover  {
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```